# Is it possible to connect a signal from javascript to qml?

Tags: javascript, qml

i'm noob in qt and qml, well my problems is i have a main.qml, here i'm importing many componentes, one of them is called HeaderConcept, in this component i make a math function, i want pass this result to other component qml, for various reasons i can't use alias for pass the result, and then my question is if i can use javascript to pass the result to other qml file, every time i invoque the math funcion in HeaderConcept for example calling a function in qml from javascript, or is best way use C++ code.
One of the reason for why not use alias property implys because of my component is CollapsiblePanel, and stay very inside of other components. I accept any tip or answer.

```
    ComprobantDelegate
    {
        id: comprobantCase

        //property alias totalOfVaucher: comprobant.totalOfVaucher
        //color: "#939393"; radius: 2; border.width: 1; border.color: "#716f6f"
    }

    ListModel {
        id: displaySettingsComprobant
        ListElement { }
    }


    CollapsiblePanel
    {
        id: panelComprobant
        width: 520
        height: parent.height
        titleText: "Datos Comprobante"
        customModel: displaySettingsComprobant
        customDelegate: comprobantCase
    }
```

this is my declaration of components in main.qml, i belive a part of problem is for Delegate of Comprobant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a signal in your HeaderConcept component, and then emit it when math function is done:

```
HeaderConcept {
   signal mathDone(int result)
   ...

   function math() {
      // math part here
      mathDone(result)
   }
}
```

When importing in main.qml:

```
HeaderConcept {
    id: hc
}

SomeOtherComponent {
    ...

    function headerConceptMathHandler(mathResult) {
        // your handling code
    }

    Component.onCompleted: hc.mathDone.connect(headerConceptMathHandler)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,but finally i decide change design and put a ComprobantDelegate how a normal object, and i can get acces direct for their members